# Upload SSH key in Bitbucket through API

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am currently building an application that allows users to deploy their projects in bitbucket to their servers. Problem is that I need to add the SSH key from the customers server to his or hers account. I noticed Bitbucket has deprecated this endpoint to store SSH keys in a users account.

Is there any way to go around this or solve this? I cannot seem to find any way.

Comment: bitbucket.org or Bitbucket Server?